# OpenPopUpPage and external Links

Tags: 2010, javascript

Is there any workaround to allow the `javascript:OpenPopUpPage(SomeExternalSiteUrl)`
works for **external links**, when I tried it it gave me `Webpage Can not be found`

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this issue. The reason is the XSS protection. jQuery fancybox is a probably the best solution. For completeness I can tell about a solution I've seen:

- An application page with a [PageViewer webpart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/display-a-web-page-on-a-sharepoint-page-by-adding-the-page-viewer-web-part-HA101857182.aspx) (which has an iframe
  inside it).

So when you open a page in a modal dialog, you open your application page:

```
OpenPopUpPage("_/layouts/MyPageViewerApplicationPage.aspx")
```

As I said, jQuery fancybox is much simpler and "fancier"...

Answer (score 0):

It should work with any URL. If you can open the URL in the browser, you should be able to open it with `OpenPopUpPage` too. What link are you passing in it?

Comment: normal url `javascript:OpenPopUpPage('http://moew-ecstest/ecs/PUBLIC_DOC?P_DOCUMENTNUMBER=11C6C844D6D36139907FEDAC26B96896');` And yes, I can open it in the browser but once I use the `OpenPopUpPage` `WebPage Can not be found` appears!

Comment: I ended up using `fancyBox` the jQuery plugin